# Issue creation through mail - Redmine in Windows 7

Tags: creation, issue-tracking, trouble-tickets

I tried a lot to config mailhandler files run through command lines etc but couldn't succeed but i m getting lots of errors. Please help me out to create issue in the tool when ever mail is received. Can you please guide me from step 1 to final step to config. What are the changes to be done in the files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change any files, just open command line, and navigate to your Redmine folder, where you have it installed, and run following command:

```
bundle exec rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host="mail.yourserver.com" username="redmine@myserver" password="pwd123" ssl=1 port=993
```

Just replace server credentials to fit your email server.

And to have emails automatically created, you need to add that command to windows task scheduler to schedule how often you want emails received and parsed.